# WPF DataTrigger doesn't work with ViewModel property

Tags: wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro, datatrigger

I have a usercontrol in XAML as below:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Presentation.Views.PersonListView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro.Platform"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         MinWidth="300" MinHeight="300">
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="List of Persons"/>
        <DataGrid SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="Persons" IsReadOnly="True"
                  cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDoubleClick] = [Action OpenPersonDetail()]" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}">
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataRowChanged}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And ViewModel class:

```
public class PersonListViewModel
{
    ...

    private bool m_DataRowChanged;

    public IObservableCollection<Person> Persons {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool DataRowChanged
    {
        get { return m_DataRowChanged; }
        set
        {
            m_DataRowChanged = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => DataRowChanged);
        }
    }

    public void Handle(Person p)
    {
        GetPersonList();
        foreach (var item in Persons)
        {
            if (!item.Version.Equals(p.Version))
            {
                DataRowChanged = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Person` is a class which contains some properties: FirstName, LastName, Age...

But it doesn't work because `DataRowChanged` is not a member of `Person`. It will work if I change `DataRowChanged` by one of property of `Person` in XAML.
Anyone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.DataRowChanged,
                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
             Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Oh, you saved my day.

Comment: @QuanNguyen I hope you learnt something out of this too, not just copying to your project and be glad that it works. Understanding the reason why this works will help build up your understanding of the whole binding engine, and makes your future binding experience much better.